# Approximating an integrable function with simple functions on compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, simple-functions

Let $f$ be an integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exists a sequence of simple functions $\{f_n\}$ such that $\mid f_n \mid \leq \mid f \mid$ for all $n$ and $f_n$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere.

Now, my question is that is it possible to have each $f_n$ as a (nonzero) linear combination of characteristic functions ***on compact subsets***? The Lebesgue measure allows each measurable set of finite measure to be approximated by compact subsets.

Then, is it possible for me to utilize this fact and setting 'the underlying sets' of each $f_n$ to be compact? I am very curious...

Comment: Yes; the important thing is that each of the indicator functions in the definition of the simple function must have finite measure, because the simple function is integrable. Thus you can approximate each indicator by the indicator of a compact set, by using the regularity properties of the Lebesgue measure. (Note that some authors define simple functions to be integrable from the start, but in this comment I am playing it safe by simply assuming that they are measurable functions that take on finitely many values).

Comment: I don’t see why not. Just approximate each indicator that makes up $f_n$ with a sequence of indicators of compact sets.